# How to remove Linux Mint to install Windows 8?

Tags: linux, windows-8, installation

I have a computer with only Linux installed. How do I remove it to install Windows 8? All I see online is about dual boot but I don't have that, just Linux on my computer. The way I installed Linux on it was with a USB drive. When I try installing Windows, I get a message drive not found.

Comment: Have you tried putting the disc in and booting from it and running the setup like normal?  Are you running into any actual issues?

Comment: I've tried loading it with a USB but when I try to install it, it says drives not found. I made the USB through Microsoft.

Comment: I actually get the Windows 8 "Install" section to appear but when I click on it it says drives or drivers not found on the USB.

Comment: you are **booting** off the usb drive right?

Comment: The issue could be that Mint was installed with ext2 or ext4 filesystem and Windows can't deal with it natively.  If you plan on wiping Linux anyway, use a partition manager to reformat to NTFS before you try installing Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This will trash your linux install: **you have been warned**

```
 sudo dd count=1k if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
```

Then hard boot. the windows install will find what looks like a blank hard disk.
proceed as normal.